# Loading Dimension and Fact table with Execute Sql Task Component in SSIS recreating

Tags: ssis

[image]I am having issue loading incremental data to dimension and fact table. I am using Execute SQL Task Component to call a stored procedure to load facts and dimensions table. Execute SQL Component Task is dropping and re-creating the tables each time the package is executed. The stored procedure works fine in Management studio. Is there any config. settings that I need to perfect to stop this challenge? Please find below my package.

[image]

Stored proc code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.Sp_DIM1
AS
MERGE dbo.tblDimSCDType2Example AS Target
USING dbo.tblStaging AS source
ON Target.SourceSystemID = source.SourceSystemID
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
                      Target.Attribute1 = source.Attribute1
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN INSERT
                                (
                                    SourceSystemID
                                    ,Attribute1
                                    ,Attribute2
                                    ,Attribute3
                                    ,DimensionCheckSum
                                )
                                VALUES
                                (
                                    source.SourceSystemID
                                    ,source.Attribute1
                                    ,source.Attribute2
                                    ,source.Attribute3
                                    ,source.DimensionCheckSum
                                );
```

Comment: It sounds like the stored proc that's being called is dropping and recreating the tables. Can you show us the code for the stored proc? And also how did you configure your `Execute SQL Task`?

Comment: Here is the code: 
create or ALTER  PROCEDURE [dbo].[Sp_DIM1]
as
merge dbo.tblDimSCDType2Example as Target
using dbo.tblStaging as source

on target.SourceSystemID=source.SourceSystemID

when matched then

update set target.Attribute1=source.Attribute1
when not matched by target then
INSERT 
  (
    SourceSystemID, 
    Attribute1,
    Attribute2,
    Attribute3,
    DimensionCheckSum
  )
  VALUES 
  (
    source.SourceSystemID, 
    source.Attribute1,
    source.Attribute2,
    source.Attribute3,
    source.DimensionCheckSum
  );

Comment: I configured the result set to none and included the exec dbo.dbo].[Sp_DIM1] into the SQL statement.

Comment: No SSIS component will drop and recreate tables by default. This is something that can only be done if you specifically add the code to do it. Your stored proc isn't dropping and creating the tables, so something else must be doing it. What are all your other `Execute SQL Tasks` doing? Can you show us the code?

Comment: It does not appear that any of the things you posted would truncate and reload a table. However we can't see the code in the package so we can't be sure. Certainly there is a step called "Truncate Staging Table". This is normal load activity though.

Comment: My troubleshooting narrowed the challenge to the last component in the package. One might not noticed this challenge if you are doing full loading(scd type 1) but extracting only modified and new records from OLTP to staging table and attempt to add them to the dimension only brings in the newly extracted records and dropped the existing records in the dimension table. Though this Microsoft documentation reads that Execute Sql Task Component recreates and load facts and dimension tables. Could that be the source of the challenge?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/execute-sql-task?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: _Execute Sql Task Component recreates and load facts and dimension tables_. No. It runs the T-SQL that you tell it to run. What T-SQL are you telling it to run?

Comment: I have earlier pasted the code. See it above. PROCEDURE dbo.Sp_DIM1. Loading only incremental records from OLTP to the dimension table is updating it with incremental records and dropping existing records. Dont do full loading from OLTP then you will experience this challenge.